# Why am I getting an “invalid active developer path” when attempting to use Git after upgrading to macOS?

Tags: mac

After upgrading to macOS Sonoma, I tried to run git from Terminal but it kept giving me the following error:
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun